# jOOQ with SQLite datebase fails to generate Java code

Tags: java, sqlite, jooq

I use jOOQ 3.16.5 to generate Java code, when I run the code, the terminal tells me to succeed, but the code is not generated, I don’t know why, so I copy the code to here and hope someone to help me

1. This is `build.gradle`

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           mavenLocal()
           mavenCentral()
           gradlePluginPortal()
           maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" 
       }
       maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public/'}
       google()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath "org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.16.5"
       classpath 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.14'
       classpath 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.30.1'
       classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.11'
   }

   plugins {
       id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "8.5.13"
   }

   dependencies {
       implementation project(":core")
       api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl3:$gdxVersion"
       api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
       api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
       api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
       api "com.badlogicgames.gdx-controllers:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxControllersVersion"
       api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

       //flyway
       implementation group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core', version: '8.5.13'
       //jooq
       implementation group: 'org.jooq', name: 'jooq', version: '3.16.5'
       implementation group: 'org.jooq', name: 'jooq-meta', version: '3.16.5'
       implementation group: 'org.jooq', name: 'jooq-codegen', version: '3.16.5'
       implementation group: 'org.jooq', name: 'jooq-meta-extensions', version: '3.16.5'
       //groovy
       implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.11'
       //sqlitejdbc
       implementation 'sqlitejdbc:sqlitejdbc:0.5.6'
       //postgresql
       implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.14'
   }
   ```
2. This is Java code to generate POJO class and other files

   ```java
   import org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool;
   import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Configuration;
   import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Database;
   import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Generate;
   import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Generator;
   import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Jdbc;
   import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Property;
   import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Target;

   public class JooqConfig {
       public static void main(String[] args) {

           Configuration configuration = new Configuration()

                   // Configure the database connection here
                   .withJdbc(new Jdbc()
                           .withDriver("org.sqlite.JDBC")
                           .withUrl("jdbc:sqlite:/home/myusername/sql/changdao.sqlite")
                   )
                   .withGenerator(new Generator()
                           .withDatabase(new Database()
                                   .withName("org.jooq.meta.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase")
                                   .withIncludes(".*")
                                   .withExcludes("" +
                                           "UNUSED_TABLE                # This table (unqualified name) should not be generated" +
                                           "| PREFIX_.*                   # Objects with a given prefix should not be generated" +
                                           "| SECRET_SCHEMA\\.SECRET_TABLE # This table (qualified name) should not be generated" +
                                           "| SECRET_ROUTINE              # This routine (unqualified name) ..." +
                                           "")
                                   .withInputSchema("public")
                           )

                           // Generation flags: See advanced configuration properties
                           .withGenerate(new Generate()
                                   .withPojos(true)
                                   .withComments(true)
                                   .withCommentsOnCatalogs(true)
                                   .withRelations(true)
                                   .withImmutablePojos(false) // if true, cannot use 'into()' method
                                   .withInterfaces(true)
                                   .withDaos(true))
                           .withTarget(new Target()
                                   .withPackageName("com.changdao.game.db")
                                   .withDirectory("desktop/src")
                           )
                   );
           try {
               GenerationTool.generate(configuration);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

This is my database

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzyF7.png]

and SQL is here, by a way, I use flyway to create a table

```sql
create table product(
     id INTEGER primary key,
     create_time TEXT
);
```

I use Java 11 and I don't know is it important

**2022-07-21**

As Lukas Eder said，I changed the code like this

```
                    .withDatabase(new Database()
                            .withName("org.jooq.meta.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase")
                            .withIncludes(".*")
                            .withExcludes("" +
                                    "sqlite_master                # This table (unqualified name) should not be generated" +
                                    "| PREFIX_.*                   # Objects with a given prefix should not be generated" +
                                    "| SECRET_SCHEMA\\.SECRET_TABLE # This table (qualified name) should not be generated" +
                                    "| SECRET_ROUTINE              # This routine (unqualified name) ..." +
                                    "")
                    )
```

and have some wrong

```
   SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
org.jooq.codegen.GeneratorException: Error generating code for catalog 
    at org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator.generate0(JavaGenerator.java:488)
    at org.jooq.codegen.AbstractGenerator.generate(AbstractGenerator.java:182)
    at org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator.generate(JavaGenerator.java:202)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run0(GenerationTool.java:912)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run(GenerationTool.java:239)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.generate(GenerationTool.java:234)
    at com.changdao.game.publicclass.JooqConfig.main(JooqConfig.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [with virtual_tables(name) as (select coalesce(sqlite_master.name, '') from sqlite_master where lower(sqlite_master.sql) like lower('%create virtual table%')) select sqlite_master.name, case when sqlite_master.type = 'view' then 'VIEW' else 'TABLE' end as table_type, sqlite_master.sql from sqlite_master where (sqlite_master.type in (?, ?) and ((sqlite_master.name not like '%!_content' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_segments' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_segdir' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_docsize' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_stat' escape '!') or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_content' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_content', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_segments' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_segments', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_segdir' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_segdir', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_docsize' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_docsize', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_stat' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_stat', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)))) order by sqlite_master.name]; near "with": syntax error
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.onError(AbstractDatabase.java:3369)
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.getEmbeddables(AbstractDatabase.java:2045)
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.getEmbeddables(AbstractDatabase.java:2065)
    at org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator.generateSchemaIfEmpty(JavaGenerator.java:527)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$1MatchSink.accept(MatchOps.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1632)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:196)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:528)
    at org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator.generateCatalogIfEmpty(JavaGenerator.java:520)
    at org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator.generate0(JavaGenerator.java:482)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [with virtual_tables(name) as (select coalesce(sqlite_master.name, '') from sqlite_master where lower(sqlite_master.sql) like lower('%create virtual table%')) select sqlite_master.name, case when sqlite_master.type = 'view' then 'VIEW' else 'TABLE' end as table_type, sqlite_master.sql from sqlite_master where (sqlite_master.type in (?, ?) and ((sqlite_master.name not like '%!_content' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_segments' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_segdir' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_docsize' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_stat' escape '!') or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_content' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_content', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_segments' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_segments', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_segdir' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_segdir', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_docsize' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_docsize', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_stat' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_stat', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)))) order by sqlite_master.name]; near "with": syntax error
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.onError(AbstractDatabase.java:3369)
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.getTables(AbstractDatabase.java:1783)
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.getEmbeddables0(AbstractDatabase.java:2087)
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.lambda$getEmbeddables$13(AbstractDatabase.java:2046)
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.onError(AbstractDatabase.java:3359)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [with virtual_tables(name) as (select coalesce(sqlite_master.name, '') from sqlite_master where lower(sqlite_master.sql) like lower('%create virtual table%')) select sqlite_master.name, case when sqlite_master.type = 'view' then 'VIEW' else 'TABLE' end as table_type, sqlite_master.sql from sqlite_master where (sqlite_master.type in (?, ?) and ((sqlite_master.name not like '%!_content' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_segments' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_segdir' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_docsize' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_stat' escape '!') or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_content' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_content', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_segments' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_segments', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_segdir' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_segdir', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_docsize' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_docsize', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_stat' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_stat', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)))) order by sqlite_master.name]; near "with": syntax error
    at org.jooq_3.16.5.SQLITE.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:3102)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:670)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:354)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:284)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch(SelectImpl.java:2843)
    at org.jooq.impl.ResultQueryTrait.iterator(ResultQueryTrait.java:300)
    at org.jooq.meta.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getTables0(SQLiteDatabase.java:373)
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.lambda$getTables$11(AbstractDatabase.java:1784)
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.onError(AbstractDatabase.java:3359)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: near "with": syntax error
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:37)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:231)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:224)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:213)
    at org.jooq.impl.ProviderEnabledConnection.prepareStatement(ProviderEnabledConnection.java:109)
    at org.jooq.impl.SettingsEnabledConnection.prepareStatement(SettingsEnabledConnection.java:82)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.prepare(AbstractResultQuery.java:210)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:307)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [with virtual_tables(name) as (select coalesce(sqlite_master.name, '') from sqlite_master where lower(sqlite_master.sql) like lower('%create virtual table%')) select sqlite_master.name, case when sqlite_master.type = 'view' then 'VIEW' else 'TABLE' end as table_type, sqlite_master.sql from sqlite_master where (sqlite_master.type in (?, ?) and ((sqlite_master.name not like '%!_content' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_segments' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_segdir' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_docsize' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_stat' escape '!') or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_content' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_content', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_segments' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_segments', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_segdir' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_segdir', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_docsize' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_docsize', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_stat' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_stat', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)))) order by sqlite_master.name]; near "with": syntax error

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [with virtual_tables(name) as (select coalesce(sqlite_master.name, '') from sqlite_master where lower(sqlite_master.sql) like lower('%create virtual table%')) select sqlite_master.name, case when sqlite_master.type = 'view' then 'VIEW' else 'TABLE' end as table_type, sqlite_master.sql from sqlite_master where (sqlite_master.type in (?, ?) and ((sqlite_master.name not like '%!_content' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_segments' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_segdir' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_docsize' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_stat' escape '!') or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_content' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_content', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_segments' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_segments', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_segdir' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_segdir', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_docsize' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_docsize', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_stat' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_stat', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)))) order by sqlite_master.name]; near "with": syntax error

Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [with virtual_tables(name) as (select coalesce(sqlite_master.name, '') from sqlite_master where lower(sqlite_master.sql) like lower('%create virtual table%')) select sqlite_master.name, case when sqlite_master.type = 'view' then 'VIEW' else 'TABLE' end as table_type, sqlite_master.sql from sqlite_master where (sqlite_master.type in (?, ?) and ((sqlite_master.name not like '%!_content' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_segments' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_segdir' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_docsize' escape '!' and sqlite_master.name not like '%!_stat' escape '!') or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_content' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_content', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_segments' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_segments', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_segdir' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_segdir', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_docsize' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_docsize', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)) or (sqlite_master.name like '%!_stat' escape '!' and "replace"(sqlite_master.name, '_stat', '') not in (select virtual_tables.name from virtual_tables)))) order by sqlite_master.name]; near "with": syntax error

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: near "with": syntax error
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8QCI.png)

Answer (score 3):

You've specified:

```java
withInputSchema("public")
```

But SQLite doesn't support schemas. so it doesn't have a `public` schema (such as e.g. PostgreSQL). Just remove this and it should work.

Note, there should have been an `INFO` message about this in your code generation output.

Comment: I upgrade jooq to 3.17.2 and upgrade jdk to 17, then run the JooqConfig main function and generate the code successful！